# How to disable and re-enable bracketed paste mode in xonsh?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, xonsh

How to disable and re-enable xonsh bracketed paste mode? It breaks pasting in interactive terminal tools that are started with keyboard shortcut.

In fish I can run functions `__fish_disable_bracketed_paste` and `__fish_enable_bracketed_paste`. Is there a equivalent for xonsh?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: ok, thank you, I will post there